# Do the intra-Schengen border controls at Euroairport have a set duration?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, airports, basel

For the past half year, flights from Euroairport to many Schengen destinations, such as Amsterdam, Munich, Berlin, Vienna and Heraklion, have consistently been leaving from non-Schengen gates.

Does this measure have a set duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is due to the current Schengen border suspensions and not some internal operational reasons at the airport, you will find the current expected end date here: https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/reintroduction-border-control_en

However, some of these suspensions have been repeatedly extended and may well be again.